# How to replace legend labels with Greek symbols for primary and secondary axis in a matplotlib bar plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, legend

I have a dataframe of 6 columns that I want to plot as bar plot.
The last 3 columns are on the on a  secondary axis. The defult legends that appear on the plot are the columns names. But I need to change the legends to Greek symbols instead. Trying to do so, I faced two issues:

1. When I add new legends names using `plt.legend`, instead of changing the existing legend box it adds  a new one.
2. When I try to change all the legends, it only change the one on the secondary axis (the last 3 columns data) but not the data plotted on the left axis.

Is there a way to solve these issues?

Additionally, how can I specify both left and right y axis limits with even spacing (or a specified spacing if possible) and y axis ticks font size and weight?

Here is an example code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# To set plotting style
plotStyleDict = {'axes.titlesize' : 18,
'axes.titleweight' :'bold',
'axes.labelsize' : 15,
'lines.linewidth' : 3,
'lines.markersize' : 10,
'xtick.labelsize' : 12,
'ytick.labelsize' : 12}

plt.style.use(plotStyleDict)

# data dictionary
dataDict = {'Year': ['1st Year','2st Year','3rd Year','4th Year'],
            'ERRh': [0, 0.71, 0.46, 0.35],
            'HRRh': [0.0, 0.66, 0.33, 0.14],
            'EREh': [0.0, 0.38, 0.20, 0.11],
            'ERRc': [1.2, 1.62, 2.04, 0.04],
            'EREc': [1.5, 1.4, 1.3, 1.1],
            'HRRc': [1.36, 2.27, 4.83, 0.09]}

# create dataframe
dfDataTest=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dataDict, orient='columns', dtype=None, columns=None)
dfDataTest.index = dfDataTest.Year
dfDataTest.drop('Year', inplace = True, axis=1)
print(dfDataTest)


# Bar plot  the dataframe with last 3 columns being on secondary axis
ax1 = dfDataTest [['ERRh', 'HRRh','EREh','ERRc', 'EREc', 'HRRc']].\
                              plot(kind='bar',color=['green','darkgreen','orange','blue','red','firebrick'], 
                              figsize=(16,6), edgecolor=['black','black','black','black','black','black'],
                              stacked=False, secondary_y= ['ERRc', 'EREc', 'HRRc'])

plt.xticks(rotation=30, horizontalalignment="center")
plt.title("Energy & Hydraulic Recoveries for Heating and Cooling",fontsize=18, weight='bold')

# specify left and right y labels with Greek symbols
ax1.set_ylabel(r'$\eta_{ER,h} , \eta_{HR,h}  , \eta_{th,h}   [-]$')
ax1.right_ax.set_ylabel(r'$\eta_{ER,c} , \eta_{HR,c}  , \eta_{th,c}  [-]$')

# change legends to Greek symbols
plt.legend([r'$\eta_{ER,h}$', r'$\eta_{HR,h}$', r'$\eta_{th,h}$',r'$\eta_{ER,c}$',
            r'$\eta_{HR,c}$',r'$\eta_{th,c}$'],loc=2)


plt.grid(True)
    
plt.show()
```

Before using `plt.legend` the plot result as follows:

[image]

With using `plt.legend` the plot result as follows:

[image]

I would like to have only one legend box (preferably the one on the top right) with all legends replaced by the Greek symbols.

Appreciate the help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier if you rename your data frame before plot:

```
orig_cols = ['ERRh', 'HRRh','EREh','ERRc', 'EREc', 'HRRc']
rename_cols = [r'$\eta_{ER,h}$', r'$\eta_{HR,h}$', r'$\eta_{th,h}$',r'$\eta_{ER,c}$',
             r'$\eta_{HR,c}$',r'$\eta_{th,c}$']
rename_dict = dict(zip(orig_cols, rename_cols))
# Bar plot  the dataframe with last 3 columns being on secondary axis
ax1 = dfDataTest [orig_cols].rename(columns=rename_dict).\
                              plot(kind='bar',color=['green','darkgreen','orange','blue','red','firebrick'], 
                              figsize=(16,6), edgecolor=['black','black','black','black','black','black'],
                              stacked=False, secondary_y= [r'$\eta_{ER,c}$',
             r'$\eta_{HR,c}$',r'$\eta_{th,c}$'])
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! @Quang Hoang
Do you how know how to set the y limits for each y axis (primary and secondary)?
When I use 'plt.gca().set_ylim([0,6])', it only set the limit for the secondary axis on the right but not the primary axis on the left.

Comment: I just fixed it. I used "ax1.set_ylim([0, 1])" for the left y axis and 
ax1.right_ax.set_ylim([0, 5]) for the right y axis.

Comment: Do you know how can I specify both left and right y axis limits with a specified spacing and y axis ticks font size and weight?